# Badge Name is Blue?

Tags: bug, design

Now some random badges on the Profile page for the mobile web is now blue! This is seemingly weird as the default and now permanent color for Badge name text is white. Here's the problem here:

[image]

Ahhhh! Now it has invaded the desktop/computer version too! Now seemingly, every version has badges with blue text. Android app has the same issues too!
Can the badge color be fixed from blue to white on the mobile version please?